# Not able to install mysql/mysql-server with yum in Centos 6.4 64bit

Tags: centos, mysql, yum

It worked initially (`yum install mysql mysql-server`), and now it won't.

I removed the working mysql from the repo with `yum remove mysql mysql-server` and tried to install from rpm source from the mysql website and it failed.

So I removed the rpm install and went to reinstall through yum, and it says the package is unavailable, what do I do? I've tried changing the repo, doing yum update, etc, reverting back my changes, doing yum update again, to no avail.

```
root@ns5000967 [/home/alex]# yum install mysql mysql-server
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: less.cogeco.net
 * epel: epel.mirror.constant.com
 * extras: centos.bhs.mirrors.ovh.net
 * rpmforge: mirror.rit.edu
 * updates: mirror.agmn.ca
Setting up Install Process
No package mysql available.
No package mysq-server available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

The most notable things that come up with yum search mysql

```
MySQL51-client.x86_64 : MySQL - Client
MySQL51-devel.x86_64 : MySQL - Development header files and libraries
MySQL51-server.x86_64 : MySQL - a very fast and reliable SQL database server
MySQL51-shared.x86_64 : MySQL - Shared libraries
MySQL51-test.x86_64 : MySQL - Test suite
```

Running 
    yum install MySQL51-client MySQL51-server

still failed in my attempts.
Right now:

```
root@ns5000967 [/home/alex]# yum clean all
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Cleaning repos: base epel extras rpmforge updates
Cleaning up Everything
Cleaning up list of fastest mirrors
```

-

```
root@ns5000967 [/home/alex]# yum list mysql mysql-server
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Determining fastest mirrors
epel/metalink                                                                               |  13 kB     00:00
 * base: less.cogeco.net
 * epel: epel.mirror.constant.com
 * extras: centos.bhs.mirrors.ovh.net
 * rpmforge: mirror.rit.edu
 * updates: centos.mirror.gtcomm.net
base                                                                                              | 3.7 kB     00:00
base/primary_db                                                                                   | 4.4 MB     00:00
epel                                                                                              | 4.2 kB     00:00
epel/primary_db                                                                                   | 5.5 MB     00:00
extras                                                                                            | 3.4 kB     00:00
extras/primary_db                                                                                 |  18 kB     00:00
rpmforge                                                                                          | 1.9 kB     00:00
rpmforge/primary_db                                                                               | 2.6 MB     00:08
updates                                                                                           | 3.4 kB     00:00
updates/primary_db                                                                                 | 4.4 MB     00:00
Error: No matching Packages to list
```

/etc/yum.conf

```
[main]
exclude=bind-chroot courier* dovecot* exim* filesystem httpd* mod_ssl* mydns* mysql* nsd* php* proftpd* pure-ftpd* ruby* spamassassin* squirrelmail*
tolerant=1
errorlevel=1
cachedir=/var/cache/yum/$basearch/$releasever
keepcache=0
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
exactarch=1
obsoletes=1
gpgcheck=1
plugins=1
installonly_limit=5
bugtracker_url=http://bugs.centos.org/set_project.php?     project_id=16&ref=http://bugs.centos.org/bug_report_page.php?category=yum
distroverpkg=centos-release
```

-

```
root@ns5000967 [/home/alex]# ls /etc/yum.repos.d/*
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo       /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Media.repo       /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo          /etc/yum.repos.d/mirrors-rpmforge             /etc/yum.repos.d/mirrors-rpmforge-testing  /etc/yum.repos.d/rpmforge.repo
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Debuginfo.repo  /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo       /etc/yum.repos.d/epel-testing.repo  /etc/yum.repos.d/mirrors-rpmforge-extras      /etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo
```

When I made my repo changes I backed up the repos to a backup directory. When I undid the change, I copied the repos back from backup.

If it could still be a repo depository problem I will follow suggestions in looking into it/checking that they are proper.

Solution:

In /etc/yum.conf it had in it's exclude list mysql. yoonix was able to point this out for me, which I over looked.

```
 exclude=bind-chroot courier* dovecot* exim* filesystem httpd* mod_ssl* mydns* mysql* nsd* php* proftpd* pure-ftpd* ruby* spamassassin* squirrelmail*
```

Comment: OP, I fixed your [formatting](http://serverfault.com/help/formatting) so it's more legible.

Comment: you seem misspelled the "mysql-server" package? Can you what "yum search mysql" shows?

Comment: Good catch! Still, it should have found `mysql`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your yum.conf, specifically the 'excludes' line in the [main] section.  It specifically lists 'mysql*'.

> exclude: List of packages to exclude from updates or installs. This should be a space separated list. Shell globs using wildcards (eg. * and ?) are allowed.

Comment: You stole my answer! I was leading him there! ;)

Comment: Thanks all. In my 12 years using unix/linux, I have never had a package I've installed suddenly go into the exclude list. Usually I leave the repos and yum.conf alone, so in my bewilderment, I never looked much at the yum.conf. But thanks all for taking the time to lead me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had used `yum remove mysql mysql-server`.  My VPS is using centos release 6.5.

I simply ran cpanel upcp script:

```
root@server [~]# /scripts/upcp
```

It has worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

- Try clearing the the yum cache.
  `yum clean all`
- Try listing packages to verify your mirrors are good and see if yum thinks it's still installed.
  `yum list mysql mysql-server`

Comment: Updated my question with the result to that.

Comment: There's something wrong with your repository configuration. If you've messed with it at all, undo it. Show us `/etc/yum.conf` and `/etc/yum.repos.d/*`.

Answer (score 1):

Just run

```
"yum install MySQL51-client.x86_64 "
```

and

```
"yum install MySQL51-server.x86_64"
```